# Stop form from submitting and show a div

Tags: javascript, html

I really don't understand why this code is not working.

What I am trying to do is stop the form from submitting if one of the fields is empty and show a div that has the error message, this is the js

```
function validate4(){
    var n4 = document.getElementById("announcementNewTitle");
    var n5 = document.getElementById("announcementNewURL");
    var n6 = document.getElementById("announcementNewDesc");
    if(n4.value != "" || n5.value != "" || n6.value != ""){
        var container = document.getElementById("successcontainer");
        container.style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

this is the html

```
<form onsubmit="return validate4()" action="" method="post">
```

Comment: What do you mean *not working*? Not working how?

Comment: Shouldn't your condition be ```if(n4.value == "" || n5.value == "" || n6.value == ""){``` if you want to show the div when one of the fields is empty?

Comment: The form is still submitting sending empty values to PHP, I just want it to not send anything nor refresh the page if all the fields are empty, then show the div called successcontainer even if it is an error container xD

Comment: @BenGuest oh god, didn't notice... thank you alot

Comment: @Andrei, no problem :)

Comment: @Andrei You can also trim the values as shown in my answer to ensure blank spaces are not submitted to server.

Comment: It should be noted that if the content being blank will break things, ensure you also validate on the server side, because it's fairly trivial for the client to modify the javascript and submit the content anyways, never trust the client to validate important data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code. If it doesn't work, open dev tools and check if any error in console.

```
function validate4(){
    var n4 = document.getElementById("announcementNewTitle");
    var n5 = document.getElementById("announcementNewURL");
    var n6 = document.getElementById("announcementNewDesc");
    if(n4.value.trim() == "" || n5.value.trim() == "" || n6.value.trim() == ""){
        var container = document.getElementById("successcontainer");
        container.style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onsubmit="validate(event)">

function validate(e) {
    var isValid = true; // perform your check here

    if (!isValid) {
        e && e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

However, you should better not attach events inline.
Preferred way of doing what you want is:

```
<form name="form-feedback">

document.forms['form-feedback'].addEventListener('submit', validate);
// note: no parentheses next to "validate"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you capturing the submit event, for instance with jQuery:

```
$('#yourFormId').on('submit', function (ev) {
  // then, where you want to stop, run:
  ev.preventDefault();
})
```

This way you can **prevent the default behavior** which is sending the form information to the destination when it is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line and you should be fine(if you don't want to use jQuery):

```
function validate4(){
    var n4 = document.getElementById("announcementNewTitle");
    var n5 = document.getElementById("announcementNewURL");
    var n6 = document.getElementById("announcementNewDesc");
    if(n4.value != "" || n5.value != "" || n6.value != ""){
        var container = document.getElementById("successcontainer");
        container.style.display = "block";
        event.preventDefault();//<----Added line
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```